# CodeQuality / Guava: clear and fill a final list or assign a new Immutablelist

Tags: list, immutability, guava, final

I have a class holding entries in a list, which can be cleared and refilled by a method from time to time.
Is it considered better practise to use a normal List as final member of the class or should I create a Immutablelist each time it's refilled, therefore losing the 'final' modifier?

The reason I'm asking is because other objects can access the List from the outside, but should not be able to change them. I want to return an ImmutableList to them, but not copy it every time the accessor is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd actually not use Guava for this use case, but rather just tools in the JDK.

What you should do is use a traditional, mutable list implementation -- probably an ArrayList -- in your class.  However, your class should implement the getList() method as something like

```
public List<Something> getList() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(internalList);
}
```

This would ensure that other objects cannot modify the list, but the list can be modified as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how often the list is modified / how big the list is, I might use a non-final `ImmutableList` field. Your inner method would construct a new `ImmutableList` each time the list changes.

If the list is modified often, or if it is very big (thus too costly to construct a new list each time), I'd use a mutable list with the `Collections.unmodifiableList()` wrapper, as Louis suggested.

Note that you might also want to consider [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) if concurrent access is important (or use a volatile ImmutableList and some kind of lock...).

Answer (score 1):

`final` modifier in Java does not protect the List itself from being modified. It just says that the reference will never point to another object, but the referenced object can change.

The immutable list is something different. The immutable list itself cannot change its content but you can point the reference to such a list on another oneas long it is not a final reference.

So it can make sense to have a final immutable list. I would always use immutable list when you do not need a mutable one.

As one main developer of guava said: "You shouldn't ask if you need an immutable list. You should better ask if you need it to be mutable." Don't know exact words..he said it in google developer channel on youtube.